# String manipulation in Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of Strings like-
`Token1:Token2:Token3`
Here `':'` is delimiter character. Here `Token3` String may contain delimiter character  in it or may be absent.
We have to convert this stream into map with Token1 as key and value is array of two strings- `array[0] = Token2` and `array[1] = Token3` if `Token3` is present, else `null`.
I have tried something like-

```
return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .map( elem -> elem.split(":"))
            .filter( elem -> elem.length==2 )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap( e-> e[0], e -> {e[1],e[2]}));
```

But It didn't work. Beside that it do not handle the case if Token3 is absent or contain delimiter character in it.

How can I accomplish it in Java8 lambda expressions?

Answer (score 6):

You can map every input string to the regex `Matcher`, then leave only those which actually match and collect via `toMap` collector using `Matcher.group()` method:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
    .map(Pattern.compile("([^:]++):([^:]++):?(.+)?")::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::matches)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.group(1), m -> new String[] {m.group(2), m.group(3)}));
```

Full test:

```
String[] inputArray = {"Token1:Token2:Token3:other",
        "foo:bar:baz:qux", "test:test"};
Map<String, String[]> map = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
    .map(Pattern.compile("([^:]++):([^:]++):?(.+)?")::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::matches)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.group(1), m -> new String[] {m.group(2), m.group(3)}));
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println(k+" => "+Arrays.toString(v));
});
```

Output:

```
test => [test, null]
foo => [bar, baz:qux]
Token1 => [Token2, Token3:other]
```

---

The same problem could be solved with `String.split` as well. You just need to use two-arg split version and specify how many parts at most do you want to have:

```
Map<String, String[]> map = Arrays.stream(inputArray)
    .map(elem -> elem.split(":", 3)) // 3 means that no more than 3 parts are necessary
    .filter(elem -> elem.length >= 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m[0], 
                              m -> new String[] {m[1], m.length > 2 ? m[2] : null}));
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Both Solution giving error- bad return type in lambda expression : String cannot be converted to String[]

Comment: @Abhijeetsrivastava are you sure that the return value of your method is `Map<String, String[]>`? Probably it's `Map<String, String>` now.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want with the following:

```
    return Arrays.stream(inputArray)
            .map(elem -> elem.split(":", 3)) // split into at most 3 parts
            .filter(arr -> arr.length >= 2)  // discard invalid input (?)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, 3)));  // will add null as the second element if the array length is 2
```